# Get current index array while loop

Tags: javascript

I want to get current index array while loop. heres my code.

**HTML**

```
<input class="btn" value="Car"><br>
<input class="btn" value="Motorcycle">
```

**Javascript**

```
var btn= document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

    for(i=0; i < btn.length; i++){

        btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(v){

            var index = btn[i];

            document.write(index);

        }, false);
    }
```

When i clicked a button the result is undefined instead 0 or 1.

Comment: Really! Just use `var index = this`, and you'll get the right result, but it still won't be an index ?

Comment: anyway, where is `btn` defined? anyway, I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/69tuE/ . Perhaps that's the most efficient way to to this, instead of getting "0" or "1" you just get the **value** of it. <-- check the javascript console in the fiddle. Moreover, in my fiddle, the index variable is useless, that's cool.

Comment: i believe this is a scope problem. `i` is not the same inside the callback.

Comment: `i` will be btn.length, so when you call `btn[i]` you're calling outside of the bounds, and getting undef.

Comment: i try what u said change btn[i] with this. it nothing happens.

Comment: @DavidSlavalia: I've provided you a fiddle which actually enclose all the answers that has been posted until now.

Comment: You should not be using `document.write` after the page has finished loading. And as adeneo said, if you want the element that was clicked, just use `this`. If you actually want the index, then see the duplicate.

Comment: @briosheje No, i want to get the index array not the value. i just forget to remove the value. i give a straight problem only want to get current index array.

Comment: @DavidSlavalia: ok, there you are: http://jsfiddle.net/69tuE/1/ . I don't understand why you want to do this, but there you are ;)

Comment: @cookie monster i try to use documentwrite( this.btn[i] ); it returns [object HTMLDivElement].

Comment: @briosheje yes, its work. it straight forward. thank you anyway. nice to meet you all :)

Comment: So what's the problem? You wanted the index number instead?